# Joblib parallel write to "shared" numpy sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, networkx, joblib

Im trying to compute number of shared neighbors for each node of a very big graph (~1m nodes). Using Joblib Im trying to run it in parallel. But Im worrying about parallel writes to sparse matrix, which supposed to keep all data. Will this piece of code produce consistent results?

```
vNum = 1259084
NN_Matrix = csc_matrix((vNum, vNum), dtype=np.int8)

def nn_calc_parallel(node_id = None):
    i, j = np.unravel_index(node_id, (1259084, 1259084))
    NN_Matrix[i, j] = len(np.intersect1d(nx.neighbors(G, i), nx.neighbors(G,j)))

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
result = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(nn_calc_parallel)(i) for i in xrange(vNum**2))
```

If not, can you help me to solve this?

Comment: Do not use the `csc` format to add values to a matrix. Read the sparse documentation.  `lil` and `dok` are better for this task.

Comment: A `dok` format matrix is a subclassed dictionary, where the keys are tuples `(i,j)`.  See if your `joblib` approach works for a plain dictionary.  Then you can tackle the job of updating a `dok` matrix (search SO).

Comment: by "number of shared neighbors for each node of a very big graph" do you mean "number of shared neighbors for each pair of nodes"?

Comment: @Joel yes, thats what I mean

Comment: You cannot do parallel writes using joblib because the shared memory is either copy or copy-on-write. The exceptions are (i) you use the threaded pool rather than process pool, or (ii) you use the shared memory arrays provided by multiprocessing (cannot be easily used with sparse matrices). For your case, it's probably simpler to just return the computed `(i, j, value)` tuples from `nn_calc_parallel`, and assemble the matrix in the main process.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same work, in my case was just ok to merge the matrixes together into one matrix which you can do this way:

```
from scipy.sparse import vstack
matrixes = Parallel(n_jobs=-3)(delayed(nn_calc_parallel)(x) for x in documents) 
matrix = vstack(matrixes)
```

Njob-3 means all CPUS except 2, otherwise it might throw some memory errors.